# Django : how to include a view.py file inside a view from another app?

Tags: django, django-views

I've made a "paginator" app, that add such SEO optimisation for all my pages.
So I need to pass all visible page url through paginator.view
But, I want to keep my apps as structured as possible.

For an example here is a view for my gallery app:

#### gallery.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from gallery.models import GalleryItem

def home(request):
    img_to_display = GalleryItem.objects.filter(published=True
                    ).order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'gallery/all.html', locals())
...
```

Now I'm doing like that form my view in paginator :

#### My current paginator.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from gallery.models import GalleryItem
from paginator.models import Page

import gallery


def custom_page(request, url):
    current_page = url

    # just for the gallery page :
    if url == 'gallery':
        img_to_display = GalleryItem.objects.filter(published=True
                            ).order_by('-date')
   
    # for all my page
    page_to_load = get_object_or_404(Page, name=url)
    template_to_load = "paginator/" + page_to_load.template_name
    
    return render(request, template_to_load, locals())
```

So I copy/paste my view and all dependencies, but that is really ugly, and not at all DRY, worth it's not maintainable. I try something like that but it doesn't work :

#### paginator.views : option1

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import gallery


def custom_page(request, url):
    if url == 'gallery':
        gallery.views.home(request)
    if url == 'anotherpage':
        anotherapp.views.home(request)
...
```

Or something like that :

#### paginator.views : option 2

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def custom_page(request, url):
    if url == 'gallery':
        include("gallery.views.py")
    if url == 'anotherpage':
        include("anotherapp.views.py")
...
```

Note: I prefer the last style option because it minimize the import at the start of the **paginator.views** file.

Thanks a lot for helping ! :)

Comment: Do you want to trigger `gallery.home` view from `paginator.custom_page`?

Comment: Yes, in some ways, in the option 1. But it doesn't work even if I include all the "from ... import ..." from my gallery.views to my paginator.views with : gallery.views.home(request). Is there a way to make option 2 works ? Maybe by specifying a parameter, like : include("gallery.views.py", home()) ?

Comment: You trying something like a redirection? What do you need in `gallery.home`  from `custom_page`?

Comment: All my pages have : name, seo_title, seo_decription,(etc..) and also txt_content and template link...

Comment: I don't understand how `custom_page` view is helping yet. You can use a `template_processor` to pass variables to every template if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I want to thanks Gocht to have sended me on a good way. So that's what I've done :

### paginator.views

```
def custom_page(request, url):
    """
    Vue d'une page statique.
    """

    if url == 'gallery':
        import gallery
        gal = gallery.views.render_gallery(request)
        gal.render()
        gallery_html = gal.rendered_content

    if url == 'xxx':
        ...

    page_to_load = get_object_or_404(Page, url=url)
    template_to_load = "paginator/" + page_to_load.template_name
    return render(request, template_to_load, locals())
```

### gallery.views

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from gallery.models import GalleryItem

def render_gallery(request):
    img_to_display = GalleryItem.objects.filter(published=True
                        ).order_by('-date')
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'gallery/gallery.html', locals())
```

But yes, now, I understand that something like simP will be more clean. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you need a mechanism which is executed before the request is dispatched to a view, I would recommend using a middleware class. You can read more about it in the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/).

Another option is to use class based views to create a SEOView which can be inherited by every custom page view of yours. Some example of how it could look like:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View

class MySeoView(View):
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # some logic for SEO 
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomView1(MySeoView):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do normal stuff for this page
    return HttpResponse(...)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # maybe some other logic for posts
    return HttpResponse(...)
```

To come back to your own options:

If you want to make #1 work, I guess you have to return the result of the view:

```
...
if url == 'someUrl':
  return gallery.views.home(request)
...
```